# Hide back button from NavViewEx(Template10.Extras.16299) UWP

Tags: uwp, navigationview, template10

I'm using a NavViewEx control of Template10.Extras.16299 in a UWP app,
but with this i need to hide built in back button of NavViewEx control, because i already visible the AppViewBackButtonVisibility property, Now i have two back button in my application.

i.e.

[image]

Template10.Extras.16299 source: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Source/Template10.Extras.16299/Controls/NavViewEx.cs

Thanks.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> hide built in back button of NavViewEx control

For hiding `NavViewEx` back button, you could modify the source code at [line 138](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Source/Template10.Extras.16299/Controls/NavViewEx.cs#L138)

```
_backButton = new Button
{
    Name = "BackButton",
    Content = new SymbolIcon
    {
        Symbol = Symbol.Back,
        IsHitTestVisible = false
    },
    Style = Resources["PaneToggleButtonStyle"] as Style,
    Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed,
};
```

You could also get `BackButton` with name by using visual tree helper then set Visibility as collapsed in `NavViewEx` loaded event.

Comment: `IsBackButtonVisible` is part of `NavigationView` and they are creating an explicit button via code behind, so even setting `IsBackButtonVisible` will not make any difference. Updating the source code itself should work as you suggested.

Comment: Sure,I will modify the reply.